# iPhone - 100k files of less than 100 bytes?

Tags: iphone, ios

I have 100,000+ strings matched with a variable number of bytes 10-300. I will often do a lookup of a string to get those bytes.

My naive way to do this in the simplest/fastest manner was to save each string as a file and simply open the file and load the bytes. This won't work since the cluster size is 8k. Can you create a 'zip' of all 100,000 files without compression and would that be a simple and fast way to access the data? Do I have to learn how to do a database?

By simple I mean least code and fast I mean this is data is looked up often so must execute quickly. I really liked the file.open(str) idea.

EDIT - I don't have control of the strings except they will be unique. It looks like Tokyo Cabinet has a restrictive license, but I'm googling key-value store. Since yep I have no queries I just need to do a lookup and sqllite seems overkill.

NSDictionary - I didn't think of this, but I'm not sure I can load the whole thing into memory and keep it there since I don't control the total size.

Comment: How long is a typical string? What's the longest string? Does each string map to some unique bytes, or do several strings possibly map to the same bytes? I'm trying to get a grip on what sort of storage is involved here.

Comment: What do you mean by 'cluster' size? Size of a cluster on the file system?

Comment: If you can actually give us a (realistic!) example of some typical  strings and what the bytes signify, it might help.

Comment: I actually figured my 100k files idea was a simple out of memory NSDictionary. Didn't know performace would be bad for this, but did know enough to know cluster size would be a problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use simple fast nosql database like Tokyo Cabinet. It's very easy to setup/use and will be faster than core data for your needs (you have no complex queries) and much faster than files.

Answer (score 4):

Sounds like you want to use core data. This would be infinitely faster than having Ks of files. My guess is that this is the fastest and most robust solution.

Comment: Infinitely faster? Really? Didn't know that Core Data was magic!

Comment: "Infinitely" should be interpreted to refer to the perceptual realm, not the mathematical (which would be nonsense).

Comment: I'm not convinced that Core Data is a good fit here -- that's an awful lot of objects he wants to persist. Plus, he's going to have to populate his Core Data database on first run, presumably from having the data in another format. Why not just keep the data in another format -- some sort of NoSQL database, say -- that can be easily bundled with the app. 
Core Data helps with loads of things (undo, object graphing, consistency etc.), none of which are requirements here -- the main reason for using it I can see is speed, and I don't think Core Data *will* be speedy here.

Comment: @Mundi Infinity can't be perceived. That's kind of the point!

Comment: I disagree. I can imagine that there might be some minor **speed** gains with direct SQLite or another database, but the coding would be much more tedious. As for **robustness** I think that this supported technology would be a safe bet. -- Yes, the initial database would have to be generated, but in the simulator that happens very fast. I have done usable implementations, including lookups, with app. 60.000 records (much longer than those described). The overhead of the other core data features should not hurt.

Comment: @occulus It can!!  - but perhaps we should take this philosophical discussion elsewhere...

Comment: I sense some speed tests of Core Data versus NoSQL etc. on the horizon! :)
I'd be worried that generating the core data database from another format, on the actual device, might take time (and battery?). But I don't have any numbers about that.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds a lot like you just have a simple mapping of string -> data.

Something like this in some generic map notation:

```
data = {
  'string1' => 0x00000001,
  'string2' => 0x00000002,
  'string3' => 0x00000003,
}
```

It also seems like you don't need to 'query' per-se, but instead you know the key precisely and just need to get its associated value.

If this is the case, you could try a simple [property list](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Property_list) and see if it is performant enough.  You can load that file and get back an NSDictionary object to use as you please.  If it's not performant (I wouldn't be surprised), a sqlite database or some small embedded key-value store should do the trick.